# Объединить 2 многомерных ассоциативных массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 2 массива. Первый типа

```
Array

    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 29.05.2017
                [price] => 4340
                [region] => Винницкая область
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 29.05.2017
                [price] => 4560
                [region] => Винницкая область
            )
```

.......

Второй типа

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Кукуруза
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Пшеница 2 кл.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Пшеница 3 кл.
        )
```

.......

В результате нужно получить  обьединенный масив  вида

```
Array

        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 29.05.2017
                    [price] => 4340
                    [region] => Винницкая область
                    [name] => Кукуруза
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 29.05.2017
                    [price] => 4560
                    [region] => Винницкая область
                    [name] => Пшеница 2 кл.
                )
  [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 29.05.2017
            [price] => 4410
            [region] => Винницкая область
            [name] => Пшеница 3 кл.
        )
```

,который нужно записать в бд.

Спасибо

Comment: вопрос, почему нужно именно пшеницу добавлять? По логике у вас должна быть кукурудза?, или нет?

Comment: прибавь их друг к другу путем сложения `$res = $arr1+$arr2; print_r($res)`

Comment: Да,именно с кукурудзы,точнее с первого елемента. По размеру оба масива одинаковые

Comment: Путем сложение получается почти то же что и при  Array_merge

Comment: "Как обьединить их так,чтобы добиться вида" :))) добиться можно разными путями, вы лучше попотроbней опишите по какой логике их объединять,какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить  ?

Comment: исправил неточности.Если еще что то нужно указать пишите

Comment: @hambit7 т.е у вас сортировка элементов в обоих исходных массивах всегда совпадает?
Значение [1] первого массива всегда совпадает с [1] второго массива ?

Comment: верн,именно так

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach ($arr_1 as $key => $value) {
        $arr_1[$key]['name'] = $arr_2[$key]['name'];

    }
```

Вроде разобрался,но все равно спасибо.